# highcharts not working properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I want to make a highchart like this http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-labels/ I have a stored procedure which count all room type reserved for every month (january :double 2,triple 4..)
I need to transmit I parameter to my stored procedure in  Roomtypereservations.RoomTypeByDate(i); When i is 1 I get data for january, i is 2 data for february......

```
  public ActionResult Gresit()
    {
   DBContext.Current.Open();

  List<Series> allSeries = new List<Series>();
  List<Roomtypereservations> rezervari = new List<Roomtypereservations>();
  for (int i =1; i < 13; i++)
  {
      rezervari = Roomtypereservations.RoomTypeByDate(i);
      var results = new object[4];

      foreach (var a in rezervari)
      {
          results = (new object[] { a.NumRezervari });

          allSeries.Add(new Series
      {
          Name = a.Room_Type,

    //Data = new Data(myData)
          Data = new Data(results.ToArray())

      });
      }
  };


      Highcharts charts = new Highcharts("chart")
          .InitChart(new Chart { DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Spline, })
          .SetTitle(new Title { Text = "Gradul De Ocupare pe luni" })
          .SetXAxis(new XAxis { Categories = Reservation.Categories })
          .SetYAxis(new YAxis
          {
              Title = new YAxisTitle { Text = "Numarul de Camere" },
              Labels = new YAxisLabels { Step = 5, Formatter = "function() { return this.value}" }

          })
          .SetTooltip(new Tooltip
          {
              Crosshairs = new Crosshairs(true),
              Shared = true
          })
          .SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions
          {
              Spline = new PlotOptionsSpline
              {
                  Marker = new PlotOptionsSeriesMarker
                  {
                      Radius = 4,
                      LineColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#666666"),
                      LineWidth = 1
                  }
              }
          })
          .SetSeries(allSeries.Select(s => new Series { Name = s.Name, Data = s.Data }).ToArray());

      return View(charts);

    }
```

But I am doing something wrong because I get this: All my data is showed  for january. What am I doing wrong?
[image]

Comment: What is the status of this question? Did the below answer work for you?  Where you able to figure out how to gather the data properly?

Comment: If my answer was what helped you, can you mark it as the approved answer?  If you found some other solution, could you add your own answer to the question and mark it as accepted?  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because you are looping through and creating a series for each data point.  You need to take the allSeries.Add statement out of the foreach structure.  Try using the below modified for structure:

```
for (int i =1; i < 13; i++)
{
  rezervari = Roomtypereservations.RoomTypeByDate(i);
  var results = new List<object>();

  foreach (var a in rezervari)
  {
    results.Add(a.NumRezervari);
  }

  allSeries.Add(new Series
  {
    Name = a.Room_Type,
    Data = new Data(results.ToArray())
  });
}
```

By the looks of it you are creating up to 12 different Series.

Comment: It is not working.It gives me this in series when i edit spage source:series: [{ data: [[1]], name: 'Triple' }, { data: [[1], [1], [1]], name: 'Double' }, { data: [[1], [1], [1]], name: 'LUXURY' },

Comment: I modified my answer try it now.

Comment: series: [{ data: [] }, { data: [1], name: 'Triple' }, { data: [1, 1, 1], name: 'Simple' }, { data: [1], name: 'Double' },{ data: [2, 1, 1], name: 'Triple' }, { data: [6, 2], name: 'Simple' }, { data: [] }, { data: [] }, { data: [] }, { data: [] }, { data: [] }, { data: [] }]
 }); that is how it looks like but i only want room type appaer once with her value for all months like this  http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-labels/

Comment: Your method for gathering the proper data is flawed. Instead of `for (int i =1; i < 13; i++)` maybe you should use LINQ to create a list of distinct room types.  Then use a foreach to loop through the room types.  Inside that foreach use LINQ to gather the required information for that particular room.  Then another foreach to build the data for each series. I do something similar [**Here**](http://goo.gl/vzKw8). Currently it looks like you are gathering the room types by date. Also, you are looping through with `for (int i =1; i < 13; i++)` and you don't have data for each iteration of **i**.

Comment: I can help you if you need assistance on how to gather your data.  If you show your model I can help you with the LINQ and foreach statements.